# How to use full 256GB RAM of my work station? MATLAB only seems to be using 75GB of RAM and not the 256GB that is available

Tags: windows, memory, matlab, workstation

I have a workstation that has 256GB RAM and 32 cores. However, when I am running some high-end simulations, the maximum used memory by the MATLAB is 33% (75 GB) and it never increases.

The simulations are quite tedious and take ~ 2 to 3 days. The purpose of buying the workstation was to speed up the high-end simulations but that is somehow not the case. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?  What edition of Windows are you using.  Please **edit** your question instead of submitting a temporary comment.

Comment: Are you _sure_ Matlab performance is actually limited because it’s not using enough RAM? Is whatever you’re running designed to be distributed among the many cores your CPU has?

Answer (score 0):

Programs use as much memory as they need to. Just having more memory doesn't mean that a program automatically *needs* or can use more memory.

Think of memory like a car park and your program like a car or a truck. A small car doesn't automatically expand to fill every space in an empty car park, it takes up a certain amount of space. A truck takes up more space but again does not expand to use *all* the space.

Apparently your simulation tops out at 75GB. That is what it *needs*. If you had less physical RAM then your computer would likely use the swap file instead, but 75GB is apparently the size of your simulation.

If you want to use more RAM then rewrite your simulation to use more.